# Trying to make button/method to refresh data displayed from API (Beginner)

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, timer

I have recently got some code working to call an API using an asynchronous function and display one set of information randomly grabbed from the API. I am now working towards a way to refresh this information. Ideally, I want it to refresh on a 24 hour timer so that it is a "Daily Quote", but at the moment I am trying to implement a button to do this so I can refresh more frequently for testing and debugging. Another thing I would like to try and fix at the moment is that in the code I have hard-coded the length of the data structure when picking a random set of information and would like this to be more adaptive to different data structure sizes. All of the code for this project can be found below

```
import SwiftUI

struct Quote: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id = UUID()
    var author: String?
    var text: String?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case author, text
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var quotes = [Quote]()
    //var buttonPressed = true
    //var numQuotes = [Int()]
    
    let randNum = Int.random(in: 1..<1643)
    
    var body: some View {
    
        var buttonPressed = Bool()
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            /*Text("Quote of the Day")
            Button(action: {
                Task{
                    await loadData()
                }
                
            }, label: {
                if quotes.count > 0 {
                    Text(quotes[randNum].text ?? "no text")
                    Text(quotes[randNum].author ?? "no author").foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
            })
            .foregroundColor(.blue)*/
            Button(action: {
                buttonPressed.toggle()
            }) {
                //buttonPressed
            }
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .border(Color.black, width: 1)
            if quotes.count > 0 && buttonPressed == true{
                Text(quotes[randNum].text ?? "no text")
                Text(quotes[randNum].author ?? "no author").foregroundColor(.blue)
                }else{
                    Text("Quote of the Day")
                }
            }.task{
                await loadData()
                
        }
    }

    func loadData() async{
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://type.fit/api/quotes") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
                quotes = try JSONDecoder().decode([Quote].self, from: data)
            //print("The count is",quotes.count)
            //numQuotes = quotes.count
            //print("numQuotes is",numQuotes)
            //print(quotes)
            //print(quotes[0].text ?? "Error")
        } catch {
            print(error)
            }
        }
    }


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Xcode is currently throwing no errors but the button is nowhere to be seen on a preview or when I run the build. I may need to move some of the code to different files which could be causing the problem but would love some more eyes to see if I can improve anything.

I have tried a variety of ways to implement a button to refresh API data but have run into many problems.

The first solution I tried messing with was setting the button action to a task of "await LoadData()" but failed on a variety of occasions.

The main errors that I was getting were in regards to the asynchronous function and the data structure being immutable.

I have since set the button action to toggle a boolean value and the data is displayed if the boolean is "true".

I am relatively new to swift and could be missing some things. Thank you in advance

Comment: Among other potential issues, `buttonPressed` should be a `@State` variable and declared *outside* the `body`

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, where you set the random quote to be displayed on a button click.
Then display the quote of the day, without re-loading the data each time.

You should read the **fundamental basics of Swift** at: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html and do a number of execises to understand Swift.

Also you need to do some tutorials, such as: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var quotes = [Quote]()
    @State var randNum = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 33) {
            Text("Quote of the Day").foregroundColor(.red)
            
            if quotes.count > 0 {
                Text(quotes[randNum].text ?? "no text").foregroundColor(.black)
                Text(quotes[randNum].author ?? "no author").foregroundColor(.blue)
            } else {
                ProgressView()
            }
            
            Button("New quote") {
               randNum = Int.random(in: 0..<quotes.count)
            }.buttonStyle(.bordered)
        }
        .task {
            await loadData()
            randNum = Int.random(in: 0..<quotes.count)
        }
    }
    
    func loadData() async{
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://type.fit/api/quotes") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            quotes = try JSONDecoder().decode([Quote].self, from: data)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT-1:

If you really want to re-load the data every time you click the button, no problema, just use this:

```
 Button("New quote") {
     Task {
         await loadData()
         randNum = Int.random(in: 0..<quotes.count)
     }
 }.buttonStyle(.bordered)
```